# Who's planning ahead? [Context in description]

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, past-perfect, past-simple

Tyler went to buy groceries because he was running out of food. Robin went to buy groceries because he had run out of food.

Who is planning ahead? Why?

Answer was Tyler but I didn't understand this one

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about logic, not language

Comment: Language philosophy is part of language learning.  Memorizing is different from understanding meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyler **was running** out of food - 'was doing' is the **past continuous** tense which we use about actions and states in progress (happening) around a particular time in the past. The running out had started, was happening, and had not yet finished. Tyler realised this and went to buy more food. He planned ahead so that he would not be without food.

Robin did not plan ahead; he actually had no food when he went shopping.

Comment: +1 Well explained.  Being in the process of running out means that one has not _yet_ actually run out.